# On Kubuntu, how do I remove the desktop toolbox and desktop icons permanently? (The settings get reset every time I log in)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

On two different systems, and on Kubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, I do this:

Click *Desktop Toolbox > Configure Desktop > Tweaks*

I **un-check** *Show the desktop toolbox*

I want to get rid of desktop icons, too, so I do:

*Configure Desktop > Location >* **check** Show files linked to the current activity

NOW, I have a clean desktop! Yay!

Next time I log in, the toolbox is there, and so are the icons. I can manually remove them, &c.

This happens on:

1. My work computer, which is a clean install of Kubuntu 18.04
2. My home computer, which has been upgraded multiple times, when it ran 16.04
3. My home computer, upgraded to Kubuntu 18.04
4. My home computer, upgraded to Kubuntu 18.04, and "reset" via `rm -rf ~/.config/plasma*`

How do I get me a clean desktop upon login?

**UPDATE:** It appears that something keeps rewriting `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`:

```
0-21:02 djh@noneedto ~> grep showToolbox ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
0-21:03 djh@noneedto ~> ls -l ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 djh djh 4465 Oct  2 21:01 /home/djh/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
0-21:03 djh@noneedto ~> touch ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
0-21:03 djh@noneedto ~> grep showToolbox ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
0-21:03 djh@noneedto ~> echo doing the GUI
doing the GUI
0-21:03 djh@noneedto ~> grep showToolbox ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
showToolbox=false
[ . . . reboot . . . ]
0-21:06 djh@noneedto ~> ls -l ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 djh djh 4465 Oct  2 21:06 /home/djh/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
0-21:06 djh@noneedto ~> grep showToolbox ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
```

Comment: I understand your frustration but you should ensure that you have *clear* and concise questions with proper titles that describe the issue. We're all here to help and the KDE devs will likely fix any issue if there is a bug.

Comment: I think the original question was more accurately descriptive but whatever suits your prescriptivism works just fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check out the [Ask Ubuntu Conduct Guidelines](https://askubuntu.com/conduct) for why this title was edited.

Comment: Ah, yes, "Be clear and constructive when giving feedback" ... I updated the title again, to clarify the nature of the problem.

Comment: This option (tweaks) has been removed in the recent updates of Kubuntu, is there any other ways to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The icons can be hidden by right clicking the desktop and going to `Configure Desktop` (`Change Desktop Background` in some older versions) then changing `Layout` to `Desktop` instead of `Folder View`

[image]

It's possible you have some kind of permissions issue with your `~/.config` directory causing the tweak toolbox setting not be saved between sessions. The checkbox you are setting is the correct way to disable the desktop toolbox. The setting is stored in `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` with a line like this:

```
showToolbox=false
```

My advice is check that file and it's contents and if it's not being updated when making the change look at the permissions for that file and it's parent directories, try running the desktop settings applet in a command line window, and ultimately file a bug on https://bugs.kde.org if needed.

Comment: I'm on Neon too and you're right, I just messed up in typing it.